# Textbox.value is returning an empty string

Tags: javascript, html

I've run into a problem here. I have a text box that is only returning an empty string.

```
var myFields = []; 

for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){ 
  var newField = document.createElement('input'); 
      newField.type = 'text'; 

  prompt.innerHTML += fields[i] + ': '; 
  prompt.appendChild(newField); 
  prompt.innerHTML += '<br>'; 

  myFields.push(newField); 
}

var finishPrompt_Action = function(){
  var results = {}
  for(var i = 0; i < myFields.length; i++){
    console.log(fields[i], myFields[i], myFields[i].value);
    results[fields[i]] = myFields[i].value;
  }

  container.removeChild(shield);
  container.removeChild(prompt);

  callback(results);
}
```

So, in the second function myFields[i].value returns an empty string.
Although myFields[i] does point to the correct input element.

Anyone got any ideas?

This is the only code that touches the textbox, and I type in the value using my keyboard.

Comment: How is `finishPrompt_Action` invoked?

Comment: To go with that, I ask that you do `console.log(typeof myFields[i]);`

Comment: Is this in IE you are seeing this error? Does it work fine in FireFox? Might be an innerHTML issue...

Comment: Ditto. In retrospect, `console.log(myFields.length);` is better.

Comment: finishPrompt is called via a button click. typeof MyFields[i] is object as expected. myFields.length = 1 as id expect. Console.log(myFields[i]) is <input type='text'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
promptDiv.innerHTML += '<br>';
```

This was the problem line. If anyone knows why or how this was breaking the code I would REALLY like to know. Commenting out this single line, fixes the problem.

Thanks,

Greg

Answer (score 1):

It's sensible to change `prompt` to something else, to prevent confusion with javascripts native `prompt` function. Furthermore it looks like your code *can* work. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nXFBH/)

Comment: I've changed the variable names to not use keywords, but this did not solve my problem.

Comment: That js fiddle doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: The fiddle is showing you the contents of `myFields` and of `Prompt`, so it's showing you that those variables are assigned and working. You'll have to work the rest out yourself.

Comment: @Kooilnc Sorry but the problem didn't persist in your JSFiddle because you fixed it without knowing.